# Not receiving the sip call using VPN in my application

Tags: android, vpn

I developing an application which make and receive the sip call.
I can make and receive the sip call on my application.

But,when I use the VPN then it not receiving the Call,Only make the call.
I Use the toyVPNClient for connecting to the VPN.

I want to receive the call on my application using the VPN that is connected by application.

Thanks.

Comment: Did u get the answer? can u share the reference link. I want to make the application like this